# Installed Windows on my machine but I can't boot into the OS I just installed

Tags: boot, uefi, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install Windows server 2016 (and tried 2012 as well) on my NAS machine which is a WD Sentinel DX4000.
I know I need to do UEFI boot to start the OS. My USB stick is UEFI bootable so it shows the stick as part of my boot options. However I don't see the OS I just installed as any of the boot options. I dug into the Windows folder under my C: volume but there is no bootx64.efi which is the one I need to boot into my Windows.

Somehow the OS I installed using the USB stick is not copying the correct boot file to C:\Windows directory so I can't boot up the system.

Any idea how I can fix the issue?

Comment: EFI files should be at the EFI partition.

Comment: under Windows\Boot\EFI, I can see bootmgfw.efi, bootmgr.efi, and memtest.efi. I don't see bootx64.efi. Not sure why the newly installed OS is not showing as a boot option.

Comment: Make sure the drive where the EFI partition is, is also the first boot drive.

Comment: I'm selecting the boot drive in the BIOS but then where I installed Windows doesn't even show as a boot option.

Comment: That can be a problem. At least the EFI partition should be in a drive that UEFI (you don't have BIOS BUT this is nitpicking) recognized as bootable and that one should come first in the boot order because the firmware needs to read from it to present the list of available OSes and options). If possible, make a EFI partition in another drive that can be selected. The installer should pick that regardless of where the system's main partition is. Also make sure the drive where the EFI partition resides is GPT, a strict requirement for Windows in UEFI mode.